# UnsatisfiedLinkError : dlopen failed (file size: 0) when installed as system app

Tags: android, qt

Installing an apk (made with Qt for Android) as a system app makes it impossible to launch.

logcat shows:

```
W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset for the library "/data/user/0/com.company.myapp/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0
```

Performing a `stat` on this file returns, as expected, a size of 0...

Installing it normally as a user is perfectly fine. Above mentioned file is no longer corrupt and the app works as expected.

Are libraries supposed to be located in `/data/user/...` when running a system app? Should it be in `/system/lib` ?
How do I solve this?

P.S: Although I have the sources, this is not my application and am unable to compile it myself. Thanks for anyone helping